# Uninstall Insignia Adapter Drivers

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, ethernet, driver

I recently bought a [Insignia USB to Ethernet adapter](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/insignia-usb-3-0-to-gigabit-ethernet-adapter-white/3510527.p?skuId=3510527&cmp=RMX&extStoreId=1399&ref=212&loc=1&ksid=434804ca-2140-40e5-b175-9edf56c00138&ksprof_id=3&ksaffcode=pg234315&ksdevice=m&lsft=ref:212,loc:2&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIvoy_46yz1wIVirjACh2R4g9wEAQYASABEgJF5_D_BwE)  I proceeded to install the drivers and it has caused me nothing but trouble since.

When I try to sign in to my profile, it opens into a window asking if I would like to use

1. WiFi network (this option is not selectable)
2. Local Network
3. My computer does not connect to the internet

No matter what option I select it states that a piece of software has not been installed and I need to try later after it is installed. It then gives me the option to **Shutdown** or **Continue** (which does nothing)

[image]

I am able to sign in when I start up in safe mode so I am able to access my files if I absolutely need to but my question is how can I find and uninstall the drivers that are causing all of these problems?

Comment: Do you have a backup of the machine, for example from Time Machine, taken before you installed the offending driver?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely your EFI partition is broken because the driver tried to make inappropriate changes to EFI.

On boot, Touch Bar attempts to boot its own OS from the EFI. If it can't boot correctly, EmbeddedOSInstallService will attempt to fix it so your Touch Bar can function again, by copying a ‘known good’ OS from:

```
/usr/standalone/firmware/iBridge1_1Customer.bundle
/Library/Updates/PreflightContainers
```

If there isn't a good OS here, Setup Assistant will ask you to connect to the internet so one can be downloaded and EFI repaired.

Make sure your internet connection is suitable per https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207567.